# How do I check if my event.target is typeof HTML input element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please see this minimum example https://codepen.io/rockmandash/pen/Rzwowd

The code is this:

[image]

```html
<div class="cool">
  <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox3">
</div>
```

```js
document.querySelector(".cool").addEventListener("click", event => {
  // In React World
  // How do I check if event.target is typeof HTML.input Element?
  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

I'm asking this question because I have thousands of input elements, in react, I will have to create thousands callback function.

So I move my function up to their parent, but then I have to validate if I am current clicking an input element.

Otherwise, I could potentially set the wrong event.target.value.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to create thousands callback function ? It's the same if you validate and call the right function. Btw you can check type using `event.target.type` when you add event.

Comment: Why you want to check the type of element?

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 26):

```
if (event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use event type

```
handleCheck = (event) => {
  // In React World
  console.log(event.target.type);
}

<div class="cool">
  <input onClick={this.handleCheck} type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" />
  <input onClick={this.handleCheck} type="checkbox" value="checkbox2" />
  <input onClick={this.handleCheck} type="checkbox" value="checkbox3" />
</div>
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  handleCheck = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.type);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div class="cool">
        <input onClick={this.handleCheck} type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" />
        <input onClick={this.handleCheck} type="checkbox" value="checkbox2" />
        <input onClick={this.handleCheck} type="checkbox" value="checkbox3" />
        
        <input onChange={this.handleCheck} type="text" />
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a good example of event delegation. See [How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

To check the type of the clicked element use [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) or [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName).

```
if (event.target.nodeName === "A")
```

Please notice you need to use upper case: `DIV`, `LI`, `A`,...

Note: In your specific case you can check the type of your `input` element like so: `event.target.type === "submit"`. But elements like `div`, `li`, `a` don't have a `type` attribute so the value of `event.target.type` will be `undefined` for them all.